# Is there a way to force a variable out of existence in Java?

Tags: java, performance, variables, scope

Basically, my goal is to be as efficient as possible by "deleting" variables when I'm done with them, even if still in scope. So far, I've been using `if(true)` to manually create a scope that defines the lifetime of variables, but I'm looking for something like, `var.close()`, a function that's only purpose is to cause a variable to essentially go out of scope and no longer have a memory location reserved for it.

The example I use below could obviously use `for()` to sidestep this particular instance(the assignment wants me not to use `for()`), but my concern is wider than variables used as indexes.
(ignore any other logic/syntax errors present, as I haven't proofread this yet)

```
package root;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class DebugEight4
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String array[] = new String[100];
      String entry = " ";
      final String STOP = "/']";

      StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer(
              "The words in reverse order are:\n"
              );

      if(true)
      /* 
       *forces x out of scope 
       * after while statement ends
       */
      {
          int x = 0;
          while(!entry.equals(STOP))
          {
              entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter another word\n" +
                "Enter " + STOP + " when you want to stop"); 
              if(!entry.equals(STOP) && x != 100)//prevents fragmentation error
              {
                  array[x] = entry;
              }
              else
              {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That\'s all! Let's see the results.");
              }
              ++x;
          }
      }/* end x scoping if
        * If the if(true) wasn't here, x would still exist!
        */

      for(int y = array.length-1; y > 0; --y)
      {
         message.append(array[y]);
         message.append("\n");
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
   }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It generally isn't possible to force the JVM to garbage collect items on the heap.  But the variable `x` which you want to "force out of existence" is a primitive and therefore lives on the stack.  We don't have control over primitives in this way.

Comment: note: simple `{}` also creates scope

Comment: The `if(true)` is unnecessary. Block scoping with just `{` and `}` would limit `x`'s scope to inside them block.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do this?

Comment: This whole idea is wrongheaded and an exercise in futility. You can't improve efficiency by "deleting" variables.

Comment: Ah, using brackets to create scope simplifies things considerably. Still, I'm vaguely suspicious that would create issues, particularly if I want to declare a variable outside of that scope, but at that particular area of code.

I figure that the larger an application gets, the more taxing little things like a variable that won't be used again taking up memory because it hasn't gone out of scope yet will become. I want to get in the habit of being as efficient as possible now, while I'm still learning.

Comment: *a variable that won't be used again taking up memory because it hasn't gone out of scope*. That's not how any of this works. *I want to get in the habit of being as efficient as possible now, while I'm still learning.* Get in the habit of writing good code and out of the habit of premature, misguided optimization while you're still learning.

Comment: @A.L.Strine This sort of thing is actually completely useless and you should unlearn it while you are still learning. Basically you are paying attention to the wrong thing. Tiny amounts of stack memory won't make a program more efficient except in very rare circumstances. Most programs are slow because they do way too many things (like building an entire webpage with jquery) or do operations that take a long time (like database queries or downloading files from a server).

Comment: Case in point: the slowest part of your loop is actually probably the String concatenation `"Enter " + STOP + " when you want to stop"` which allocates an array behind the scenes. (But even then, it only does it once when it shows the dialog box so it doesn't matter. Showing a dialog box to a user is like the entire age of the solar system compared to the speed of a CPU clock cycle.)

Comment: @shmosel When the teacher fails the student, the student must ask on stack overflow. _shakes maracas_

Comment: Your teacher told you to use scope for performance optimization? That's horrifying...

Comment: @Radiodef Good point. So, I'm taking a CS certification course at a technical school, and a lot of the details like that just won't be taught to me. Basically, their concern is, "Can they code? Do they have a basic knowledge of the languages taught?" I've often wondered which actions take more effort to complete, but I'm not sure what that field of study would even be called to do research. Any idea?

Comment: @shmosel Well, student teacher. All I have available right now...

Comment: The "field" is called micro-optimization and it should be avoided until you have a demonstrated need *and* the skills and tools to do it properly. Focus on writing code that's clean, readable and maintainable.

Comment: Deallocating a local variable is actually one of the fastest things a program can do (of this sort of thing). Local variables are pretty much always stored on [the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation), so "deallocating" stack memory could be as simple as decrementing a pointer.  (Objects are different though, in Java. Objects are never stored on the stack in Java.) I don't really know what field this sort of thing is considered. I think it's just computer science.

Comment: The field of which actions take more effort to complete is called performance analysis, and it rests on measurement, not guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what scopes are for. You don't need to invent your own scoping system. Any variable should be declared in the smallest possible enclosing scope. But that's as far as you need to go with this. It is a visibility principle, not an efficiency principle, as all the stack needed for a method is allocated on entry to the method, and inner scopes don't correspond to bytecode instructions in any way.

Comment: I started out in this program with C++, and it was suggested that to be more efficient, some programmers would do what you're talking about in C++ to speed up the program. It sounds like you're saying that doesn't apply to Java? It's all just about making the code more readable?

Comment: It doesn't apply to C++ either. It is not more efficient. The same principle about allocating all the stack on entry to the method applies in both languages, and C, and every other language I have ever used too. It is actually *slower* in C++ if objects are being allocated on the stack, as they have to be constructed and destroyed every time the scope they're declared in is entered and exited. It is all about making the code *safer* and more readable. The fewer lines of code that have access to the variable, the better.

Answer (score 0):

To create a more-limited scope is easy enough. Just create a new block:

```java
public static void whatever() {
    int a = 5; // Exists until end of method
    {
        int b = 5; // Exists until end of outer block
        {
            int c = 5; // Exists until end of inner block
        }
        // c is no longer accessible
    }
    // b is no longer accessible
}
```

I'd recommend against this for a few reasons:

- It's harder to read for little gain
- The compiler or JIT [can automatically figure out the lifetime of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis) and automatically handle what you're attempting to do
- You can't overlap variable lifetimes this way (nesting means that the most-nested variable must expire off the stack **before** less-nested ones)

Comment: "The compiler or JIT can automatically figure out the lifetime of variables and automatically handle what you're attempting to do"
You use the word "can" - will it not do this under certain circumstances? Also, thanks, I had no idea.

Comment: One big circumstance is the optimization not being implemented. Another is useless cases, like a method that's going to end very soon without calling other methods (where conserving stack space might help out), so it can just wait until the method ends, where all the stack-allocated stuff from the current method is automatically "deleted" by simply moving the stack pointer back to where it was before the current method was called.